# How to validate access_token(Azure AD OAuth 2.0) in web API?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD OAuth 2.0 authorization flow for my Spring Boot Microservices + Angular2 application.
Flow of my application

1. (1st request to my Spring Boot application from frond-end) Spring boot application redirect it Azure login page.
2. User enters his credentials
3. Authorization server sends POST request to `redirect_uri`, this request have the `authorization_code` along with other user info(like first name, last name and user id).
4. Then I get `bearer` token and `refresh_token` using `authorization_code`

Now I want to sent `bearer_token` to other microservice which will validate the `bearer_token`.

My question is how can validate `bearer_token` and retrieve the owner of that token in other microservices ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you use the default configuration for Azure AD OAuth 2.0 which returns JWT-encoded tokens. There are few benefits of this type of tokens - you could extract information such as granted scopes from the token itself and you could avoid sending a validation request to the Authorization server by checking the token signature.

## Configuring JWT token validation

You would need to configure Resource server (your Web API) to use the JWT tokens:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }
 
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
 
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setVerifierKey(obtainAzureADPublicKey());
        return converter;
    }
 
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
 }
```

This code (with small modification) was taken from the excellent [blog post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt) by Eugen Paraschiv (aka Baeldung).

## Obtaining Azure signing key

You would need to get an asymmetric public encryption key that the Azure AD uses to sign the issued tokens and return it from the `obtainAzureADPublicKey` method.

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#validating-tokens) you would have to first obtain the meta-info about the JWT signature key endpoint from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration` (by retrieving the value of `"jwks_uri"` property from the result).

Then you would need to obtain the proper key from that URL.

Note that Azure AD changes this information from time to time so you cannot do it only once at the startup of your application. However, caching it for at least 24 hours would be a good idea.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Is it (from security point of view) okay to store refresh token and bearer token in cookies ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the one who generated the access token should be responsible for validating it which is usually the authorization server, I understand Azure is your authorization server so there where you should validate your token

Comment: Thats where i am stuck. How can I verify it from Azure AD ?

Answer (score 0):

For any HTTP request you are sending to the `microservices`, you should add the following in the header:

```
   Authorization: Bearer bearer_token
```

`bearer_token` is the token given by the `microservices` for that user.

NOTE: I don't know what is a `microservice` means here, which I am assuming is some Web API service.

Comment: Yes, we can say that microservice is one kind of Web API. But my question is how can microservice/Web API will determine if that token is valid or not? Also, it should be able to retrieve user's info associated with that token to do some authorization part.

Comment: The onus of verifying whether the token is valid or not lies on the `microservice`  (or `Web API Server`) but not you. If it sends authorization error, it means your `bearer_token` has expired and time to refresh the `bearer_token` using the `refresh_token`. The method through which you can do this is also provided as a Web API service. Usually they also provide the number of seconds that a `bearer_token` is valid for, try to use that.